# Breaking the twocolumn to add a large figure

Tags: graphics, floats

I am using

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
```

and I need to place a very large figure composed of 12 smaller plots:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti1}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti3}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti5}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti7} 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti9}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti11}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti13}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti15}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti17}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti19}    
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti21}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti23}
    \label{fig:Phase}
    \caption{Flow at the tube ending.}
\end{figure}
```

That's either very unwieldy or the plots have to be really scaled down to fit the twocolumn enviroment. I want to do this instead:

[image]

**How this can be done?**

Comment: `\begin{figure*}\end{figure*}` instead of `\begin{figure}\end{figure}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should modify the environnement from `figure` to `figure*`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{tmp}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{tmp}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

So in your case:

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti1}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti3}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti5}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti7} 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti9}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti11}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti13}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti15}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti17}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti19}    
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti21}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.28]{usti23}
    \label{fig:Phase}
    \caption{Flow at the tube ending.}
\end{figure*}
```